# Handling Arrays & Objects in componentDidMount (React)

Tags: reactjs

Imagine that you have a component that bridges an imperative API to react component, for example, Mapbox API.
So you made yourself a Map component and you want the every time that user changes the center prop, the map updates to the new coordinates.  It looks something like this:

```
class Map extends Component {
    el = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount(props) {
      this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.el.current,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: this.props.center,
        zoom: this.props.zoom
      });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // notice this condition
      if (prevProps.center !== this.props.center) {
        this.map.setCenter(this.props.center);
      }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.map && this.map.remove();
    }

   render() {
      return (
        <div ref={this.el} className="map" />
      )
   }
}
```

And we use it like so:

```
<Map center={[35.173906, 32.706769]} zoom={16} />
```

Now here is the catch: **since we pass a new array every time, the condition is always true**, even for changes unrelated to the map at all.

I made a simple example to demonstrate it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pmz40wkm8j

[image]

Notice that when we increment the counter, the map center updates too.

**There are 2 ways I can think of to solve it:**

1. using `_.isEqual` which will work. but I want if it will affect performance for large arrays and Objects, for example, you can pass a pretty lengthy object of layers to mapbox.
2. Enforce the user to use `Immutable.js`, but it doesn't feel right because not everyone feels comfortable with it

What will be the best approach to handle that in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

I think `_.isEqual` is superfluous here, just use this function in your `componentDidUpdate`

```
centerPropsHasBeenChanged(prevProps, props) {
 return (
   props.center[0] !== prevProps.center[0] || props.center[1] !== prevProps.center[1]
 )
}
```

**Option 2**

If you're using big arrays (so not coordinates, but something else), it looks like the fastest option is to `JSON.stringify()` and compare then